# add new column of a number

Tags: linux, awk

I am writing the following codes to extract data from an existing file using awk within a for loop.

```
for c in {1..300}
do
awk '{if($28==1) print $12,$26,$28}' file1.txt > file2.txt
done
```

This is ok and I have file2.txt
Now, I want to add a new column containing c generated from the for loop above. 
I do this but it does not work.

```
awk '{if($28==1) print $12,$26,$28, paste c}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

This only works when I replace c by a real number such as 1,2,...
Finally, I want to append file1.txt to file2.txt, i.e. every time the loop runs it will add new data to file2.txt.
I have this but it seems not the best:

```
awk <file2.txt>> file_final.txt
```

Can you please give me some advice? Thank you!
Phuong

Using the approach recommended by William below, I am able to do produce outputs that I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: what do you mean with `paste c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rm file2.txt
for c in $(seq 1 300); do
  awk '$28==1{print $12,$26,$28,c}' c=$c file1.txt >> file2.txt
done
```

Comment: your approach works well and produces expected results. The final file2.txt contain the last c (which is 300). 
However, I would want to add file2.txt every time the loops runs to a file file. SO that in the end I have a final file with data, and c runs from 1:300.
I use the following code but not working:

Comment: for c in $(seq 1 300); do awk '$28==1{print $12,$26,$28,c}' c=$c file1.txt > file2.txt; awk <file2.txt>> final_file.txt;

Comment: Are you using `>>` in the loop?  If that does not do what you want, then I do not understand what you want.  If you use `>`, then you will only get the data from the last iteration.

Comment: But perhaps you are simply looking for `for c in $(seq 1 300); do awk '$28==1{print $12, $26, $28, c}' c=$c file1.txt; done > file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer the shell variable `c` to awk:

```
awk -v c="$c" '{if($28==1) print $12,$26,$28,c}' OFS=', ' file1.txt
```

`-v c="$c"` creates an awk variable, called `c`, which has the value of the shell variable `$c`.

#### Example

Using fake input data:

```
$ c=2; echo {1..28} | awk -v c="$c" '{if($28==1) print $12,$26,$28,c}' OFS=', ' file1.txt
12, 26, 1, 2
```

#### Example in a loop

Let's start with this sample file:

```
$ cat file1.txt 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 1
```

Now, let's run the awk command in a loop and look at the output:

```
$ for c in {1..3}; do awk -v c="$c" '{if($28==1) print $12,$26,$28,c}' OFS=', ' file1.txt; done >file2.txt
$ cat file2.txt
12, 26, 1, 1
12, 26, 1, 2
12, 26, 1, 3
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. However it seems the output is not correct. It looks like this for first row:  21.2616488643708,1,1, paste {1...3}

Comment: Exactly what command did you run?  What is the source of the expression `{1...3}`?

Comment: It that possible to include the awk comment within for loops as my original question. That is because under my for loops there are some model running command, then produce output which is file1.txt above.
I ran this:  for c in {1..3}; do awk -v c="$c" '{if($28==1) printf "%s,%s,%s, paste %s\n",$12,$26,$28,c}' file1.txt > file2.txt; done

Comment: I did the loop example and added the output to the answer.  The expression `{1..3}` only works under bash.  If you see `{1..3}` in the output, that means some other shell was used, likely `dash`.

Comment: hi John, my expected out put is: 12, 26, 1, 1. It means replacing "paste 1" by 1

Comment: @hieu Well, that is actually easier.  Answer updated to remove `paste` and use comma-space as the output field-separator.